# Failed to login to the system using PHP

Tags: php

May I know why it not redirect to the page that I've been looking for and I have some problem where if I enter the correct username its still show that I enter the wrong username/password. Here the snippet of my code. Anyone can help me? Thank you. And anyone how to make a session?

```
 <?php
    require('db.php');
    session_start();
    // If form submitted, insert values into the database.
    if (isset($_POST['username'])){

        $username = stripslashes($_REQUEST['username']); // removes backslashes
        $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$username); //escapes special characters in a string
        $password = stripslashes($_REQUEST['password']);
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$password);

    //Checking is user existing in the database or not
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE username='$username' and password='".md5($password)."'";
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die(mysqli_error());
        $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if($rows==1){
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            header("Location: home.php"); // Redirect user to homeA.php
            }else{
                echo "<center><div class='form'><br><br><h1>Username/password is incorrect.</h1><br/>Click here to <a href='main.php'>Try Again</a></div></center>";
                }
                }
    else{
?>
```

Comment: Did you try the code with out `stripslah` and 'mysqli_real_escape_string'? And also your code is at risk with the way you're using your variable directly inside the `SQL` change it and start using prepared statements.

Comment: Dont use `stripslashes`, nor escaping, parameterize. Don't use md5. Also `exit` after your `header`.

Comment: Output `$query ` and execute it on the DB, does it work and return a result?

Comment: So hard to answer questions like this as your not answering one thing, you need to cover the SQL Injection issue, stop using stripslashes, dont store passwords as md5, dont use $_REQUEST, checking for vars before using, exiting  after setting a location header, so many things to cover for so little code and for a `1` rep user. Should just be closed as `go back to the tutorials`.. my2cent

Comment: Does it show any error?

Answer (score 1):

To start of with, please use prepared statements instead of string concatenation to construct sql statements. An easy solution to this problem would be to use PDO. Second, **never ever hash passwords using MD5**. Password hashing in PHP is done using the `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` functions.
Below is an example of how a login page could work using previously mentioned methods.

```
// Create a new PDO object using host (might be 127.0.0.1), dbname (your database name), user (your database username) and pass (your database password)
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);

if (isset($_POST['username'])) {

    $stmt = $dbo->prepare('SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = :username');
    $stmt->bindParam(':username', $_POST['username']);

    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        $row = $stmt->fetch();

        if (password_verify($_POST['password'], $row['password'])) {
            // User password matched. Log them in
        } else {
            // User password didn't match
        }
    } else {
        // There was a problem executing query
    }

}
```

You will also need to hash your password using `password_hash()` when creating your users.

```
password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT)
```

Comment: Which security flaws are you talking about then?

Comment: "you really shouldn't use mysqli. It suffers from a handful of securityflaws" should say "Please use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of string concatenation to construct sql statements". Unfortunately this likely doesn't answer the "question" - mostly because the source of the problem isn't apparent from what's in the question.

Comment: Well, technically not direct security flaws, but rather big risks of creating security holes. Mysqli requires many steps to ensure that there are no risks of injecting queries and similar. PDO handles escaping and much more for you, so the risk of making missing out on important steps.